# How to plot a shape only if a condition is met in Pine Script v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

New to coding so please forgive my ignorance. I'm trying to figure out how to trigger the plotshape command for my "longEntry" signal only if my "longSetup" condition is met within the previous 5 bars. I have the code compiled and working correctly for the most part, but right now the "longEntry" is being plotted a lot, and I want to restrict it to only plot with this additional condition. Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
longSetup = src < lower and src < slsma and src < EMA50 and macd < signal
longEntry = ta.crossover(src, slsma) and src < EMA50 and rsi < 40 and k > d

plotshape(longSetup, title="Long Setup", style=shape.cross, color=color.new(color.green, 40), size=size.small, location=location.bottom)
plotshape(longEntry, title="Long Entry", style=shape.circle, color=color.new(color.yellow, 40), size=size.small, location=location.bottom)
```

So, ideally, the longEntry would work like this:

```
longEntry = ta.crossover(src, slsma) and src < EMA50 and rsi < 40 and k > d and longSetup appears within the last 5 bars
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not really elegant but it should work :
your longSetup is a serie, so you can access the last value of longSetup with longSetup[x].
In your case, you can try :

```
longSetup = src < lower and src < slsma and src < EMA50 and macd < signal
LongSetupAppearWithinTheLast5Bars = longSetup and longSetup[1] and longSetup[2] and longSetup[3] and longSetup[4]
```

Then, your longEntry would be :

```
longEntry = ta.crossover(src, slsma) and src < EMA50 and rsi < 40 and k > d and LongSetupAppearWithinTheLast5Bars
```